# Get all duplicate values from object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following object deserialised from JSON data

```js
[{
  "EmployeeNumber": "169",
  "EmployeeNumberError": "",
  "EmployeeFirstName": "saj"
}, {
  "EmployeeNumber": "169",
  "EmployeeNumberError": "",
  "EmployeeFirstName": "Carlton"
}, {
  "EmployeeNumber": "1002",
  "EmployeeNumberError": "",
  "EmployeeFirstName": "Stanley"
}]
```

I want to get all duplicate 'EmployeeNumber' from the object using javascript or jQuery. Can any one help me?

Comment: Duplicate how, what makes it a duplicate? Is it the same key, the same employee number, same name ?

Comment: Loop through your data and keep a map with all `EmployeeNumbers` and their location in the array. If there is already an entry for that `EmployeeNumber` you have a duplicate add both records to a duplicates map...duplicates map key could be `index` of original array and value could be the record itself.

Comment: I need Duplicate EmployeeNumber only.ie "EmployeeNumber :169" is repeated twice,So I need the output "169"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var v = [{
    "EmployeeNumber": "169",
    "EmployeeNumberError": "",
    "EmployeeFirstName": "saj"
  }, {
    "EmployeeNumber": "169",
    "EmployeeNumberError": "",
    "EmployeeFirstName": "Carlton"
  }, {
    "EmployeeNumber": "1002",
    "EmployeeNumberError": "",
    "EmployeeFirstName": "Stanley"
  }];

  var a = [];
  for (x = 0; x < v.length; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < v.length; y++) {
      if (v[x].EmployeeNumber == v[y].EmployeeNumber) {
        a.push(v[x].EmployeeNumber)
      }
    }

  }
  a = jQuery.unique(a);
  alert(a[1]);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```